# jQuery Json Array Issue?

Tags: jquery, json

Im using the Blueimp [Jquery File Upload widget](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki) and its returning something that looks like an array of json data. If you look at the below example (not all json data to make it easier to read):

```
[{"name":"10 (2).jpg","size":264843,"type":"image\/jpeg"}]
```

Now, if I want to access the 'name' value of said array, how would I do it?
Using the below, gets this done, but then my log gets full of 'undefined' values as well when the array is only a single element long:

```
    $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
        console.log(file.name);
    });
```

Doing console.log(data.result) spits the above array example i give, while trying to do console.log(data.result[0]) just spits out

```
[
```

Clearly Im not getting something. $.each method works fine with multiple elements, but why is it failing with a single item? Furthermore; and MORE IMPORTANTLY, how do i get the "name" value since in this current application thats all the info I reall need.

Comment: Try replacing from $.each(data.result) to $.each(data)

Comment: No, its definitely in the 'result'; just data doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You have a string, so data.result[0] will give the first char. It seems you have to parse the string:

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON( data.result )
```

This might work.

Comment: That doesnt seem to work either, but this appears to be malformed JSON. If you look at this part: "size":151512 <- isnt that supposed to be "size":"151512" ? Still, doesnt explain why it the .each method works with multiple instances, but with a single instance it fails.

Comment: The "size":151512 is correct, numbers in JSON are ok. But what I am wondering is about jQuery does not decode the json, as it usually does if it determines the mime-type is json.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I added the "BlueImp" widget option to include:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

And suddenly console.log(file.name); works. Silly because thats the DEFAULT data type! Dont know why it starts working with the above, frankly dont care - thanks for the help guys.